# Missing Microsoft.Devices.Sensors in Visual Studio (nothing inside "Add references..." too)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I want to use sensors in my Windows Phone 8.1 app. I use [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff431810%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and they said that I have to paste these usings into my code:

```
using Microsoft.Devices.Sensors;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
```

I can't. Visual Studio says: "The type of namespace does not exsists".
I found in Internet that I should look for it in "Add References..." window, but there isn't anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

`Microsoft.Devices.Sensors` is for applications targeting Windows Phone 8 (not 8.1) and Windows Phone **Silverlight** 8.1 (not the same as Windows Phone 8.1). As per the tutorial, the namespace you should be using for Windows Phone 8.1 is `Windows.Devices.Sensors`

> In addition to the APIs described in this topic from the Microsoft.Devices.Sensors namespace, you can also program the phone’s sensors by using the similar classes in the Windows.Devices.Sensors namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Windows.Devices.Sensors instead.

Comment: And the MS reference is here:[Windows.Devices.Sensors namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.devices.sensors)